# Rails generate ends up in no command 'rails' found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

i installed ruby on rails following this tutorial: [Tutorial i used](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04), using rvm. 
when i run: `rails -v` i get: `Rails 5.1.3` so i assumed my rails installation was a success.

So i used `rails new myproject` and it didn't pop any error. 
I used `bundle install` and then i tried to use `rails​ ​generate​ ​scaffold​ ​Product​ ​name:string​ ​description:text price:float​ ​stock:integer` which ended in the following error:

```
No command 'rails​' found, did you mean:
 Command 'rails' from package 'ruby-railties' (universe) 
rails​: command not found
```

When i run `gem list` rails is listed. 
The "EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY" field in `gem environment` is already in `$PATH`

I have been stuck with this problem for the last 6 hours and read several post, what do you think might be the problem?

For some extra info, my ruby version is: `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]`, also i'm using ubuntu gnome `GNOME Shell 3.18.5`, rvm version `rvm 1.29.2 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]`

Comment: There in newly generated project folder, the “domestic” gemset is used. Try to bun `bundle install` there in the first place, that should help.

Comment: I had already used `bundle install` in my project folder, it finished and the `rails generate` problem was still there.

Comment: Would you try `bundle exec rails generate ...` please?

Comment: When i used that command the result was: `bundler: command not found: rails​` `Install missing gem executables with 'bundle install'`